# How to get Eclipse CDT debugger to show contents of unicode strings?

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt, icu

I have a C++ project that uses ICU Unicode strings heavily. Recently, I started using the Eclipse CDT IDE, but I cannot watch the contents of the strings while debugging. The only options are printing them to logs or casting them to `std::string`.

Does anyone know of a way to get Eclipse to show the contents of ICU strings in the "expression" view?

**Update:** It seems this is a [known issue with Eclipse](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=42679). GDB does not parse the contents of Unicode strings. It's possible to add macros/functions to enable GDB to parse them, but how can I make Eclipse use them in the "expressions" window while debugging?

Comment: Do you mean `class UnicodeString` or `UChar[]` (which is UTF-16)?

Comment: I mean `class UnicodeString`, but the debugger will show neither.

Comment: I haven't ported this to GDB yet, but here's some MSVC code for showing UnicodeString:  http://userguide.icu-project.org/dev/codingguidelines#TOC-Windows-Microsoft-Visual-Studio

Comment: You probably want to implement a GDB pretty printer for UnicodeString

Comment: "the only options are printing them to logs or casting them to std::string." printf debugging is often the only tool you have. get good at it rather than faffing around trying to fix substandard tools.